# Fetch only one value from API with PHP

Tags: php, api, stock

I have recently been trying to get stock data from financialmodelingprep.com and I successfully found a code;

```
set_time_limit(0);

$url_info = "https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/stock/real-time-price/AAPL";

$channel = curl_init();

curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_URL, $url_info);
curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

$output = curl_exec($channel);

if (curl_error($channel)) {
    return 'error:' . curl_error($channel);
} else {
    echo $output;
}
```

This code outputs: `{ "symbol" : "AAPL", "price" : 324.83 }` And I was wondering how I could fetch only the "price" number (324.83) and store it in a php variable.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try even play with the code? 

Untested code but try

$myPhpVar = $output['price'];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output you're getting is in `json` format. Convert it to an array using [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and then you can pull any value you'd like from the array:

```
$array = json_decode($output, true);
var_dump($array['price']);
```